# Как из объекта Object вытащить свойство, в свойстве

Tags: c#

В моем проекте есть функция, которая возвращает тип object, в этом типе есть вся нужная мне информация. Представлена в виде разных свойств.
Достаю я эти свойства так.

```
   public void AddDataToJboss(object Data)
        {
            // проверяем удаленный объект или нет
            bool IsDeleted = (bool) Data.GetType().GetProperty("IsDeleted").GetValue(Data, null);

            // проверяем тип класса
            var ClassName = Data.GetType().GetProperty("ClassInfo").GetValue(Data, null);


        }
```

Далее в свойстве ClassInfo есть вложенное свойство ClassType. Как в случае вложенности подступаться к свойству, которое находится внутри другого свойства.

Comment: Почему вы пользуетесь рефлексией, а не ООП средствами?

Comment: Я нашел ответ тут , что такой вариант мне подходит. Хотя что вы имеете ввиду под ООП средствами? Приведение типов? Но в моем случае object возвращается из внутренней функции фреймворка, которым я пользуюсь. Вот нашел такой вариант. если есть best way), буду рад.

Comment: Покажите как объявлено свойство `ClassInfo`, не совсем ясно про вложенные свойства.

Comment: @defaultlocale Внутри этого свойства еще есть куча свойств, среди них нужное мне

Comment: Оно возвращает класс? В этом классе объявлено еще одно свойство? Покажите код этого свойства, объяснять это словами не очень эффективно.

Comment: Я это вижу только в отладчике, так как это функция внутри фремворка, и я только на выходе получаю object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/983030/3129992

Comment: может помочь [`dynamic`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic)

Comment: OK. Расскажите как можно больше об этих свойствах. Скажите какого типа это свойство. Дайте ссылки на документацию. Выложите скриншот из отладчика (но только вместе с чем-нибудь из вышеперечисленного, не только скриншот). В общем, помогите людям дать Вам конкретный ответ.

Comment: Написал ответ о том, как решать вашу задачу в ООП

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот законченный пример консольной программки. Имеется класс `A` со свойством типа `ClassInfo`. Создаём экземпляр этого класса и получаем значения его свойств с помощью рефлексии, а также с помощью `dynamic`.

Код с `dynamic` гораздо лаконичнее. Но не стоит сильно обольщаться: работает он тоже очень медленно.

```
using System;

namespace ConApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var a = new A { IsDeleted = true, ClassInfo = new ClassInfo { ClassType = "something" } };

            GetInfoReflection(a);
            GetInfoDynamic(a);
        }
        static public void GetInfoReflection(object data)
        {
            bool isDeleted = (bool)data.GetType().GetProperty("IsDeleted").GetValue(data, null);
            Console.WriteLine(isDeleted);

            var classInfo = data.GetType().GetProperty("ClassInfo").GetValue(data);
            var classType = classInfo.GetType().GetProperty("ClassType").GetValue(classInfo);
            Console.WriteLine(classType);
        }
        static public void GetInfoDynamic(dynamic data)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.IsDeleted);
            Console.WriteLine(data.ClassInfo.ClassType);
        }
    }
    class A
    {
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public ClassInfo ClassInfo { get; set; }
    }
    class ClassInfo
    {
        public string ClassType { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: _работает он так же медленно_ - вроде не совсем так же :)

Comment: @Grundy - согласен, исправил.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Да именно про это я спрашивал.

Answer (score 0):

> Как в случае вложенности подступаться к свойству, которое находится
>   внутри другого свойства

Так и подступаться, через рефлексию.

Хотя было бы гораздо проще и эффективнее создать класс-модель для `Data` и при получении привести типы соответствующим образом.

Comment: Проблема в том, что каждый раз набор свойств в Object будет разный, в моем случае я и пытаюсь вытащить название класса, к которому потом привести Object

Comment: А синтаксически как именно подступиться?

Comment: Создайте несколько моделей. Зная какой объект к Вам пришёл Вы сможете спокойно его привести к нужном типу.

Answer (score 0):

С точки зрения ООП: {`Data` имеет некоторые конкретные свойства} = {`Data` реализует некий интерфейс}

```
interface IClassTypeContainer
{
    object ClassType { get; }
}

interface IClassNameContainer
{
    bool IsDeleted { get; }
    IClassTypeContainer ClassInfo { get; }
}
```

Тогда:

```
public void AddDataToJboss(IClassNameContainer data)
{
    var isDeleted = data.IsDeleted;
    var classInfo = data.ClassInfo;
    //...
}
```